# Filter for array and model selection in Angular UI-Select is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a Json like this:

```
$scope.people = [
{ name: 'Niraj'},
{ name: 'Shivam'},
{ name: 'Arun'},
{ name: 'Mohit'}]
```

and a variable like `var array = "Niraj,Shivam";` Now i want to filter the names of people from the array. And need to make sure that array value need to be by default selected in `Angular UIselect`.

[image]

As shown in figure. **And also i need to make sure that on the click of click me button only the newly added value need to be shown(Desired) or if we are getting all the values then also there is no issue.**

Here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pe14Wy09CC0uOchFd2md?p=preview)

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] *in the question itself*, **not only on a third-party site**.

Comment: The code needs to be **in the question, here on Stack Overflow**, not only on Plnkr. When Plnkr removes that code, this question will be useless. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution to filter as well as listing of value based on condition. 
This is my `demo.js` file

```
    'use strict';

var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $interval) {

  $scope.oldArray = [];
  $scope.people = [
    { name: 'Niraj'},
    { name: 'Shivam'},
    { name: 'Arun'},
    { name: 'Mohit'},
    { name: 'Koushik'},
    { name: 'KedaBro'},
    { name: 'Tripathi'},
    { name: 'Nlma'}, 
    { name: 'Nshma'},
    { name: 'BsCoder'}
  ];
  var people = $scope.people;
  var oldArray = [];
  // Now these two values by default need to be selected in multiple selection
  var array = "Niraj,Shivam";
  array = array.split(",");
  for(var i=0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
    oldArray.push({
      name : array[i]
    });
  }
  //filter is wokring fine now
  var filteredArray = people.filter(function(itm){
  return array.indexOf(itm.name) < 0;
  });
  $scope.filteredArray = filteredArray;
 console.log(filteredArray); 

  $scope.multipleDemo = {};
  $scope.multipleDemo.selectedPeople = [];
  for(var  i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
    $scope.multipleDemo.selectedPeople.push({name : array[i]});
  }
  $scope.submitValue = function(){
    console.log($scope.multipleDemo.selectedPeople);
  }
});
```

This is my `html` file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AngularJS ui-select</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

        <!-- ui-select files -->
        <script src="./select.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./select.css">

        <script src="./demo.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">    
    </head>
    <body class="ng-cloak" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl">
      <h1>Multiple Selection</h1>
      <ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.selectedPeople" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" sortable="true" close-on-select="false" style="width: 500px;">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="person in filteredArray">
          <div ng-bind-html="person.name"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
      <button name="button" ng-click="submitValue()">Click me</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[Link to Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8RvdwaXuwszCYG1Vwq6T?p=preview)